# How to quote $1 in yasnippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

Suppose, I have the following yasnippet:

```
my $dir = __FILE__;
$dir =~ s/(.*)\/.*/$1/;
```

`$1` here is the regular expression first match. Not yasnippet special symbol. How can I quote it, so it is inserted into the code as is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#plain-text):

> Arbitrary text can be included as the content of a template. They are usually interpreted as plain text, except $ and `. You need to use \ to escape them: \$ and \`. The \ itself may also needed to be escaped as \\ sometimes.

So use `\$` to get a literal '$' in your snippet.